# How to ungracefully close a connection?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

Is there a function in Winsock that ungracefully closes a connection (i.e. causes an `RST` packet to be sent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, first set the `SO_LINGER` option to `{true, 0}` with `setsockopt()` and then close the socket. Any pending data is lost and the normal FIN/ACK close sequence is replaced by an RST.

Don't do this. You may lose all data in flight, and upset the other end.

Another way to produce this accidentally is to close the socket when it still has pending inbound data.